# How to use synchronization in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Output.html#Parallel-Output):***

> To avoid this you can use the `--output-sync` (`-O`) option.  This
>   option instructs `make` to save the output from the commands it invokes
>   and print it all once the commands are completed.  Additionally, if
>   there are multiple recursive `make` invocations running in parallel,
>   they will communicate so that only one of them is generating output at a
>   time.

***So, given a makefile:***

```make
# A "recipe" that will always fail.
all::
    @foo bar baz
```

***And running, we get:***

```make
# A "non-synchronized" run
$ make
make: foo: Command not found
makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127

# Synchronize!
$ make --output-sync
makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Can you see a difference between the 2 runs?

Well, they both fail!

But, in the first run, Make let's us know ***why*** it failed, as it "let-through" the failing error(s) from the recipe:

```console
make: foo: Command not found
```

But, for the second run, all we get, is:

```console
makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

But ***why***? Why did it fail..Were there any debugging errors - from the recipe - that it failed? Sure there were! As evident by the 1st run! So, Why is Make so quick to ***hide*** them?

Now - that Make is hiding the error message - all we can do here, is: to guess!

We are very lucky here, because we know that "foo..." is an invalid command, so ***probably***, somewhere, behind the curtains, this command was not acceptable, for this very reason.

But, consider this:

- Imagine, when you have some typo in a command?
- Now, imagine a typo in complex makefile!
- Now, imagine the typo in a complex makefile run recursively!
- Now, imagine all that in a makefile that runs for long period of times, outputting considerable amount of output!

How, then, could it be still justified for Make to "hide" some debugging errors, and show others?

(***Versions note:*** All versions supporting synchronization, hence: 4.0 and up).

Answer (score 0):

I had opened a bug report on this the other day here https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47365

It should be fixed now http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/?id=14b2d7effb0afd75dfd1ed2534e331784f7d2977

I guess you can build the latest version from source or wait until they make another official release. I'll be building from source as I need this fix ASAP :)