# GNU Make 4.0 --output-sync=target doesn't show the final error

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, makefile, continuous-integration

I'm tweaking a build system to run faster by executing a bunch of the targets in parallel by using `-j24`. Since I want the output to be somewhat readable I'm using `--output-sync=target`. This works great when there are no errors and performs exactly as I would expect it to. I'm finding that when there is an error Make will not output it like it does normally when running things sequentially. This is a big issue since the build is being run in Jenkins and various people will need to see the failures if there are any.

The only other discussion I could find on this issue was this [How to use synchronization in makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164266/how-to-use-synchronization-in-makefile) which doesn't seem to have any comments/answers. Does anyone know if there is a solution to this issue?

FWIW here's what the command looks like when the build is run in parallel: `make --output-sync=target -j$(nproc)`

Comment: Have you tried the latest release, GNU make 4.1?

Comment: I haven't, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately the same behavior is in 4.1 as well.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  I suggest you report it on https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=make or else send a request to bug-make@gnu.org.  It's unlikely that random questions on StackOverflow will lead to someone fixing the problem... :)

Comment: Fixed in Git: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/?id=14b2d7effb0afd75dfd1ed2534e331784f7d2977

Comment: Awesome! I had opened a bug on this yesterday like you had suggested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being an actual bug in Make https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47365

It has been fixed here as MadScientist pointed out in his comment http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/?id=14b2d7effb0afd75dfd1ed2534e331784f7d2977